# php if condition

Tags: php

I can't find anything wrong with this... This should work right?

```
function ConfirmedNumber()
{
$rs = mysql_query("CALL ConfirmedNumber('" , $_SESSION['UserID'] . "',@Active)");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs))
    {
        if ($row['Active'] = 1)
        {
        return true;
        }
    }
return false;
}
```

Assuming the Stored procedure returns a single row with the value '1' in it then I can call the function like this right?

```
if (ConfirmedNumber())
{
//do some stuff.
}
```

Comment: `$row['Active'] = 1` should be `$row['Active'] === 1`

Comment: yep, `$row['Active'] = 1` will always be true, since he can assign 1 to $row['Active'], therefore return true.

Comment: @adlawson: `$row['Active'] === 1` --- will always be false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on my comment:

`if ($row['Active'] = 1)` should be `if ($row['Active'] == 1)` to work correctly.

If you want to avoid accidentally doing this in future, you could write your if statements like this:

```
if (1 == $row['Active'])
```

This way, you can't accidentally use `=` as PHP will throw a Fatal Error. You can read more about [Comparison Operators at PHP.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

---

[Comment below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7225341/php-if-condition/7225361#comment-8686468) with the full answer:

> The call to the stored proc... line $rs = mysql_query("CALL ConfirmedNumber('" . $_SESSION['UserID'] . "',@Active)"); had a comma instead of the period in the initial post.

Comment: What type do all the fields retrieved from mysql have?

Comment: @adlawson This still isn't working for some reason. Could it be that my function call is bad?

Comment: @kulingar If you have a row in which `'Active' == 1`, then everything looks ok, but without seeing a data dump it's difficult to tell why. The function call is perfectly fine.

Comment: @adlawson I run the stored procedure and come up with one result, column exactly titled "Active" and 1 in the cell (I personally hate how MySQL changes boolean to a tinyint with a length of 1). I'm exceptionally new to MySQL and PHP. I'm going to look into this data dump to see what's up. Will post with response. Thanks.

Comment: Just as an FYI, the call to the stored proc... line    $rs = mysql_query("CALL ConfirmedNumber('" . $_SESSION['UserID'] . "',@Active)"); had a comma instead of the period in the initial post. So if you update your answer to include it I'll be grateful. Additionally, I forgot to start the connection to the database in the function. :(

Comment: +1 for [Yoda conditions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349378/new-programming-jargon-you-coined/2430307#2430307)!

Answer (score 1):

you forgot your operator in your IF statement. Change it to this:

```
if ($row['Active'] == 1)
```

or even shorter

```
if ($row['Active'])
```

Comment: The equivalence operator is making no difference. Is my call to the function correct? Or are you referring to the if statement that calls the funciton? hrm.

Answer (score 0):

it can be something like this

```
    function ConfirmedNumber($id)
    {
    $rs = mysql_query("CALL ConfirmedNumber('" . $id . "',@Active)");
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs))
        {
            if ($row['Active'] == 1)
            {
            return true;
            }
        }
    return false;
    }
ConfirmedNumber($_SESSION['UserID']);
```

Comment: No need to waste the bandwidth passing the session variable to the function. Might as well call it inside the function. Plus this isn't what my problem was. :(

Comment: the condition must be like that $row['Active'] == 1